# How do I bridge an ethernet device to the wireless network interface from within a VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VM?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, virtualbox, bridge, wireshark

I have a VirtualBox Ubuntu VM, the "VM", set up on my primary Windows machine, using bridged VirtualBox connections to the wireless interface and the ethernet port (i.e. Ethernet <-> bridge <-> VM, and Wireless <-> bridge <-> VM). I have a secondary IoT device, the "IoT" which normally connects over ethernet directly to a router. However, I want to use the VM to Wireshark the communications that occur between the IoT and any mobile devices that control the IoT from the same wireless network. While I can IP-forward (via iptables) from ethernet-to-wireless without issue and provide the IoT access to the internet through my VM, and Wireshark regular internet traffic, it does not act as if any of my mobile devices are on the same network as the IoT. I cannot use my mobile devices to directly control the IoT via HomeKit, nor can I ping the IoT from the wireless network like I can ping the VM.

I've looked at many guides and wikis ([example](https://www.chrisjhart.com/Bridge-Network-Interfaces-on-Ubuntu-22.04/)) which didn't work for me, and many of the guides [from Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Configuring_bridging_in_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Finterfaces) refer to /etc/network/interfaces, which my version of Ubuntu doesn't have, apparently using NetworkManager instead, which I am unfamiliar with. I'd just like my IoT to appear on the wireless network in the same way my VM does, using bridged networks, but every time I bridge the wireless & ethernet interfaces from within my VM, I lose all connection from the VM and it doesn't work to connect the IoT either. Slaves connected, interfaces up and running, still no luck.

In sum: How do I set up my network like **IoT -> ethernet -> VM -> wireless network**, such that mobile devices on this wireless network can directly ping the IoT device, with the VM Wiresharking the traffic?

Comment: technically you cannot bridge as client (STA) a wireless interface, unless you change the AP's configuration to 4 addresses mode (instead of 3), and *all* other clients. virtualbox just make things look like it was done, probably with a method similar to Linux' ipvlan/ipvtap. So Considering this is about an hypervisor running under Windows and something that is dubious, I'd look for something that doesn't involve bridging wireless.

Comment: (what? 4 addresses instead of 3??? I know Ethernet uses 2 addresses! But Wifi is not Ethernet: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header )